# Export gt_group object to PDF file in R

Tags: r

I have following code in R which exports a table containing summary rows along with histogram, box plot per each row to a PDF file using R's "gt" package

```
result <-
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species,
               names_to = "Vars",
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  nest_by(Vars) %>%
  mutate(n = nrow(data),
         mean = round(mean(data$Values), 2),
         median = round(median(data$Values), 2),
         hists = list(ggplot(data, aes(Values)) + geom_histogram()),
         plots = list(ggplot(data, aes(Values)) + geom_boxplot()), .keep = "unused") %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(gghist = NA, ggplot = NA) %>%
  {dat <- .
    dat %>%
    select(-hists, -plots) %>%
    gt() %>%
    text_transform(locations = cells_body(c(ggplot)),
                   fn = function(x) {
                     map(dat$plots, ggplot_image, height = px(100))
                   }) %>%
   text_transform(locations = cells_body(c(gghist)),
                  fn = function(x) {
                    map(dat$hists, ggplot_image, height = px(100))
                  })
  }

gtsave(result, filename = "test.pdf")
```

I need multiple "gt_tbl" objects of above kind to be exported to single PDF in multiple pages. I found that "gt_group" of "gt" package is used to group multiple "gt_tbl" objects, but I am unable to export an object of type "gt_group" to PDF using "gtsave" method.

I am getting following error:
*Error in writeImpl(text) :
Text to be written must be a length-one character vector*

Can anyone help?